# array to string in java

Tags: java, arrays, replace

I have tried to replace a string in an array then conver it to string but it was not like I want. Here is my example:

```
    String data = "ABC   00 0 03 54            BTT";
    String[] tokens = data.split("\\s+");
    for(int i=0; i<tokens.length; i++){
        if(tokens[i] == "BTT"){
           tokens[i] = tokens[i].replace("BTT"," ");
        }
    }
    data = Arrays.toString(tokens);
    Log.log(Log.VRB, "DEBUG: field =" + data);
```

OUTPUT:
DEBUG: field =[ABC, 00, 0, 03, 54, BTT]

But I had tried to get this output: DEBUG: field = ABC  00 0 03 54

Can anyone give me the idea how can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Loop on the array and print the values yourself...

Comment: Use tokens[i].equals("BTT"), '==' in Java does not work a you'd think for string comparison.

Comment: Ok Jacob, I will change the comparing like  tokens[i].equals("BTT") but the issue is my code doesnt replace BTT with space or delete it. also the output is not like input as ABC 00 0 03 54. it is like [ABC, 00, 0, 03, 54, BTT]

Comment: check my answer below that solves your issue

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use .equals() method then iterate over the array to print it as string as follows:

```
    String data = "ABC   00 0 03 54            BTT";
    String[] tokens = data.split("\\s+");
    for(int i=0; i<tokens.length; i++){
        if(tokens[i].equals("BTT")){
           tokens[i] = tokens[i].replace("BTT"," ");
        }
    }
    data = Arrays.toString(tokens);
    Log.log(Log.VRB, "DEBUG: field =" + data);       

  StringBuffer b =new StringBuffer();
  for(int i = 0; i< tokens.length; i++)
  {
      b.append(tokens[i]);

      if(i< tokens.length -1)
      {
          b.append(" ");
      }
  }

  Log.log(Log.VRB, "DEBUG: field =" + b.toString());
```

Comment: Thanks Wael, let me try it and I will let you know what will be the result.

Comment: By the way shouldnt I remove this part?

Comment: data = Arrays.toString(tokens);
    Log.log(Log.VRB, "DEBUG: field =" + data);

Comment: yes you can remove it. I kept it to let you see the output of both at same time

Comment: Thanks Wael, now I am compiling my code it will take time and I will let you know if it works.

Comment: it works Wael. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

```
String data = "ABC   00 0 03 54            BTT";
String[] tokens = data.split("\\s+");
data = Arrays.stream(data.split("\\s+"))
            .filter(s -> !"BTT".equals(s))
            .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
Log.log(Log.VRB, "DEBUG: field = " + data);

Output => DEBUG: field = ABC 00 0 03 54
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont use == if you want to compare value of 2 strings, because it is used for working with their address in heap.

Please replace  `tokens[i] == "BTT"` into `tokens[i].equals("BTT")`
.It will be compare their value.

Sorry for not-good English :)

Answer (score -1):

There is this method for Strings: .substring(int beginning, int end);

```
 Log.log(Log.VRB, "DEBUG: field =" + data.substring(1, data.length()-1));
```

It removes the first and last char in the string (the [ and ]).

Comment: The  [ ] are added by the Array class to represent the values in the array

Answer (score -1):

Use String Class replace and replaceAll utility methods.

String data = "ABC   00 0 03 54            BTT";

Log.log(Log.VRB, "DEBUG: field =" +  data.trim().replaceAll(" +", " ").replace("BTT", ""));